# How to install D-link DWA-172 (ID 2001:3318) driver

Tags: wireless

Just to share the solution that allowed me to install the D-Link AC600 DWA-172 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.
Kernel: 4.4.0-31-lowlatency

---

1. Check your hardware ID by running `lsusb` to confirm you have the same adapter.

   ```
   ID 2001:3318 D-Link Corp.
   ```
2. In the Terminal run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
   git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
   cd rtl8812au
   ```
3. Then you'll need to edit the file `os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c` to add :

   ```
   {USB_DEVICE(0x2001, 0x3318),.driver_info = RTL8821}, /* D-Link DWA-172 */
   ```

   in the `#ifdef CONFIG_RTL8821A` section.
4. In the Terminal run:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe 8812au
   ```
5. Reboot

---

Note: I rebooted after the install and again after running `modprobe`... but I understand this was not required.

Hope that this info is helpful to others.

Take care!

Sources:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=121127

Comment: I had to do `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` (not `8812au`)

Comment: Quick update: the additional line in the usb_intf.c is already added in the newer versions.