# D-Link DWA172 (ID 2001:3318) not working

Tags: wireless

So I followed the steps here: [How to install D-link DWA-172 (ID 2001:3318) driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861717/how-to-install-d-link-dwa-172-id-20013318-driver)

**I always fail on the installation, here is the process:**

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812au
```

No problem here, I installed everything at their latest version, cloned the driver in my Documents folder and "cded" on it;

Added the magic string in `os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c` under `#ifdef CONFIG_RTL8821A` section (after `/*=== Customer ID ===*/`);

```
{USB_DEVICE(0x2001, 0x3318),.driver_info = RTL8821}, /* D-Link DWA-172 */
```

And then I do: `make` it spits out some gibberish (much gibberish), and then `sudo make install`,

this is what I get:

`install -p -m 644 rtl8812au.ko  /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ /sbin/depmod -a 5.4.0-42-generic`

And theeen i do `sudo modprobe 8812au` and this is the result:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic
```

In one comment in the post I was referring this whole time somebody said that he had to do `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` instead of 8812au only, when I do that it doesn't say anything and I am immediately able to write again on the cli, so I thought that I won, but then after the reboot nothing happened, not even running again `modprobe rtl8812au`.

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: What is the result for `modprobe -c | grep 3318`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. I had no idea about aircrack-ng and these drivers. For future readers, note that there are updated installation instructions on the URL of the repo. In my case, just `sudo make dkms_install` and restart was enough. No modprobe.